# BehaviorSubject subscribe causing infinite loop in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, rxjs

i'm trying to use a BehaviorSubject tied to a SocketIO implementation to broadcast changes to all components that subscribe to it. i am using it because i want to be able to send “old” values to new subscribers.

here is my client socket implementation:

```
// socket.js

const { Observable, Subject, BehaviorSubject } = require('rxjs');
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const axios = require('axios');

const { environment } = require('../../environment/environment');

module.exports = class {
  this.socket = io(environment.api.notifications);
  this.notifications$ = new BehaviorSubject();

  this.listener$ = new Observable(observer => {
    // listening for NEW_NOTIFICATIONS event from socket server
    this.socket.on('NEW_NOTIFICATIONS', () => observer.next());
  }).subscribe(async () => {
    // hit the API for notifications when the event occurs 
    console.log('listener sub called')
    const notifs = await this.getNotifications();

    // tell the BehaviorSubject to dispatch the new notifications
    this.notifications$.next(notifs);
  });

  async getNotifications() {
    console.log('getNotifications')
    try {
      let response = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: `${environment.api.notifications}/notifications/getAll`,
      });

      return JSON.parse(response.data.body);
    } catch (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error('error getting notifs:', err);
        observer.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

is is initialized elsewhere in the app...

```
// index.js

const Notifications = require('../socket.js');

module.exports = new Notifications();
```

here's the component using the class:

```
// component.tsx

import React, { ReactElement, useState } from 'react';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

import Notifications from '../../index.js';

export const Component = (): ReactElement => {
  const [notifications, setNotifications]: [any[], Function] = useState([]);
  const notifs$: BehaviorSubject<any> = Notifications.notifications$;
  
  notifs$.subscribe(notifs => {
    console.log('notifs!', notifs);
    setNotifications(notifs);
  });
```

the results are:

```
listener sub called
socket.js: getNotifications
Component.tsx: notifications: Array(4)
Component.tsx: notifications: Array(4)
Component.tsx: notifications: Array(4)
Component.tsx: notifications: Array(4)
...
zone-evergreen.js:171 Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14815)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:17034)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18610)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:480)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1621)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone-evergreen.js:1647)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
```

i can tell that the `notifs$.subscribe` is what is "causing" the infinite loop because the rest of the observable streams functions are only called once as intended, but i'm not sure what is telling it to run. from what i understand, the subscribers of `Notifications.notifications$` should only "trigger" when `.next()` is called, but they seem to trigger recursively. the socket client is only seeing the `NEW_NOTIFICATIONS` event once in the cycle so it should only trigger once.